# Acronyms section does not appear

Tags: glossaries, texstudio, indexing, acronyms

Using the code given below, the Acronyms section does not appear. I am using Texstudio as an editor.
Could someone please tell me what is the problem ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{CBD}{CBD}{Convention on Biological Diversity}
\newacronym{CCC}{CCC}{UN Framework Convention on Climate Change}
\newacronym{CMS}{CMS}{Convention on the Conservation of Migratory Species of Wild Animals}
\newacronym{FAO}{FAO}{Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations}

\begin{document}

\phantomsection
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long, toctitle={Acronyms}, title={Acronyms}]
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{chapter1}
\ac{CBD}
\ac{CCC}
\ac{CMS}
\ac{FAO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example does not compile ... What is inside `chapter1.tex` or `acronyms`?  Why do you load `hyperref` **after** `glossaries`? Why `\setcounter{page}{0}`? Have you run the `makeglossaries` script at all?

Comment: I have edited the question by adding more details. `\setcounter{page}{0}` is just for having less pages (2 instead of 3); you can omit it if you want. `hyperref` is needed because otherwise I get the following error: 'Undefined control sequence. \phantomsection'

Comment: I know about `hyperref` ;-) There's a clear statement in the `glossaries` documentation that you should load `glossaries` **after** `hyperref` Please combine your document and not such spaghetti code here. And `\setcounter{page}{0}` will only reduce the logical page number, but not the number of pages being shipped out!

Comment: I am sorry, I have misunderstood you.. I have loaded `glossaries` after `hyperref`, but still getting the same result.

Comment: Could you please tell what do you mean by  "combine your document" ?

Comment: He means to put all your code in a single codeblock. That is, instead of `input{acronyms}`, just type the contents of `acronyms` into the main tex document itself. Ditto for `chapter1`. Either that or consider using the `filecontents` package.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have edited the question and combined the document.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer By "run the `makeglossaries` script" you mean entering Tools -> Glossary ?. If so, I have tried it, by I got the following error: "makeglossaries.exe: The script engine could not be found. makeglossaries.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe""

Comment: @din: Well, having `perl` installed is deliberate then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `glossaries` package documentation:

1) After running LaTeX on your document, you should have files with the extensions .glo and .ist.

2) Run the following command with `makeindex` (either with command prompt for Windows or bash console for Unix-like users), replacing myDoc with your main document name.

```
makeindex -s myDoc.ist -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo
```

This creates an output file with the extension .gls.

3) Then run LaTeX on your document again, and you should be able to see the Acronyms page:

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me what does step 2) accomplish excatly ?

Comment: `makeglossaries` script is much easier

Comment: The `makeindex` application reads the .ist file as the style file, and the .glo as an input file (contains your glossary information) and outputs a .gls file, which can be read by LaTeX on your next run.

Comment: Your solution works. I also found another solution based on @ChristianHupfer comments: I tried to run `makeglossaries` but did not succeed, so I have installed `activeperl`, run `makeglossaries`, then run my tex file, and it works. Thank you!